# Parse Google Custom Search API Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, api, google-custom-search

I am trying to parse from the below Google Custom Search API call the fields "og:image" and "og:title" of the "metatags" array. I honestly do not know how this is possible to be done as I cannot find any resources online. I need to retrieve this information as I need to display the contents of the fields in my app. If it is not possible to parse only the "metatags" array how can it be done for the whole API?
Thank you

```
    {
  "kind": "customsearch#search",
  "url": {
    "type": "application/json",
    "template": "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q={searchTerms}&num={count?}&start={startIndex?}&lr={language?}&safe={safe?}&cx={cx?}&sort={sort?}&filter={filter?}&gl={gl?}&cr={cr?}&googlehost={googleHost?}&c2coff={disableCnTwTranslation?}&hq={hq?}&hl={hl?}&siteSearch={siteSearch?}&siteSearchFilter={siteSearchFilter?}&exactTerms={exactTerms?}&excludeTerms={excludeTerms?}&linkSite={linkSite?}&orTerms={orTerms?}&relatedSite={relatedSite?}&dateRestrict={dateRestrict?}&lowRange={lowRange?}&highRange={highRange?}&searchType={searchType}&fileType={fileType?}&rights={rights?}&imgSize={imgSize?}&imgType={imgType?}&imgColorType={imgColorType?}&imgDominantColor={imgDominantColor?}&alt=json"
  },
  "queries": {
    "request": [
      {
        "title": "Google Custom Search - 4009900360937",
        "totalResults": "6",
        "searchTerms": "4009900360937",
        "count": 6,
        "startIndex": 1,
        "inputEncoding": "utf8",
        "outputEncoding": "utf8",
        "safe": "off",
        "cx": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  "context": {
    "title": "Google"
  },
  "searchInformation": {
    "searchTime": 0.36736,
    "formattedSearchTime": "0.37",
    "totalResults": "6",
    "formattedTotalResults": "6"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "customsearch#result",
      "title": "Wrigleys Airwaves Menthol & Eukalyptus 3x 10 Dragees ...",
      "htmlTitle": "Wrigleys Airwaves Menthol &amp; Eukalyptus 3x 10 Dragees ...",
      "link": "https://www.codecheck.info/m/essen/suesswaren/kaugummi_kaudragees/ean_4009900360937/id_368832/Wrigleys_Airwaves_Menthol_Eukalyptus_3x_10_Dragees.pro",
      "displayLink": "www.codecheck.info",
      "snippet": "Wrigleys Airwaves Menthol & Eukalyptus 3x 10 Dragees. Kaugummi & \nKaudragees. Produktbeschreibung. Menthol kaugummis. Menge / Grösse. 3 \nStangen a ...",
      "htmlSnippet": "Wrigleys Airwaves Menthol &amp; Eukalyptus 3x 10 Dragees. Kaugummi &amp; \u003cbr\u003e\nKaudragees. Produktbeschreibung. Menthol kaugummis. Menge / Grösse. 3 \u003cbr\u003e\nStangen a&nbsp;...",
      "cacheId": "f04ddBPMjcMJ",
      "formattedUrl": "https://www.codecheck.info/...4009900360937/.../Wrigleys_Airwaves_ Menthol_Eukalyptus_3x_10_Dragees.pro",
      "htmlFormattedUrl": "https://www.codecheck.info/...\u003cb\u003e4009900360937\u003c/b\u003e/.../Wrigleys_Airwaves_ Menthol_Eukalyptus_3x_10_Dragees.pro",
      "pagemap": {
        "cse_thumbnail": [
          {
            "src": "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQuvPSLNQtg0Ie2_MxSlKIIRNWENp1ezJboQcYIpatdxd5QDks4eJnRIrY",
            "width": "225",
            "height": "225"
          }
        ],
        "metatags": [
          {
            "apple-itunes-app": "app-id=359351047",
            "og:image": "http://www.codecheck.info/img/51821803/1",
            "og:type": "Product",
            "twitter:card": "summary",
            "twitter:title": "Wrigleys Airwaves Menthol & Eukalyptus 3x 10 Dragees",
            "og:site_name": "Codecheck.info",
            "twitter:domain": "CodeCheck",
            "twitter:url": "http://www.codecheck.info/m/essen/suesswaren/kaugummi_kaudragees/ean_4009900360937/id_368832/Wrigleys_Airwaves_Menthol_Eukalyptus_3x_10_Dragees.pro",
            "og:title": "Wrigleys Airwaves Menthol & Eukalyptus 3x 10 Dragees",
            "language": "DE",
            "og:description": "Wrigleys Airwaves Menthol & Eukalyptus 3x 10 Dragees",
            "twitter:image": "http://www.codecheck.info/img/51821803/1",
            "fb:app_id": "122709251073903",
            "apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style": "black",
            "viewport": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimal-ui, user-scalable=0, maximum-scale=1",
            "apple-mobile-web-app-capable": "yes",
            "twitter:description": "Wrigleys Airwaves Menthol & Eukalyptus 3x 10 Dragees",
            "og:locale": "de_DE",
            "publisher": "Codecheck.info",
            "og:url": "http://www.codecheck.info/m/essen/suesswaren/kaugummi_kaudragees/ean_4009900360937/id_368832/Wrigleys_Airwaves_Menthol_Eukalyptus_3x_10_Dragees.pro",
            "google-play-app": "app-id=ch.ethz.im.codecheck",
            "format-detection": "telephone=no"
          }
        ],
        "cse_image": [
          {
            "src": "http://www.codecheck.info/img/51821803/1"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "customsearch#result",
      "title": "NEW WRIGLEY'S AIRWAVES SUGAR FREE CHEWING GUM 3 PACK",
      "htmlTitle": "NEW WRIGLEY&#39;S AIRWAVES SUGAR FREE CHEWING GUM 3 PACK",
      "link": "https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/NEW-WRIGLEYS-AIRWAVES-SUGAR-FREE-CHEWING-GUM-3-PACK-30-PIECES-42g-/292246791829",
      "displayLink": "www.ebay.co.uk",
      "snippet": "... Gummy, Soft Sweet & Marshmallow. Food Aisle: Pantry, Food Specifications: \nSugar Free. Brand: Wrigley, Type: Chewing/ Bubble Gum. EAN: 4009900360937\n ...",
      "htmlSnippet": "... Gummy, Soft Sweet &amp; Marshmallow. Food Aisle: Pantry, Food Specifications: \u003cbr\u003e\nSugar Free. Brand: Wrigley, Type: Chewing/ Bubble Gum. EAN: \u003cb\u003e4009900360937\u003c/b\u003e\u003cbr\u003e\n&nbsp;...",
      "cacheId": "fOoNmVeHk30J",
      "formattedUrl": "https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/NEW-WRIGLEYS...3...-/292246791829",
      "htmlFormattedUrl": "https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/NEW-WRIGLEYS...3...-/292246791829",
      "pagemap": {
        "offer": [
          {
            "areaserved": "United Kingdom and many other countries | See details",
            "availableatorfrom": "Luton, United Kingdom",
            "pricecurrency": "GBP",
            "price": "3.69",
            "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock",
            "itemcondition": "New"
          }
        ],
        "cse_thumbnail": [
          {
            "src": "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTcul7IOdYe6L0tYz-KZzyMuqXmIGrCxSdEwjXLdDWiT-GVfeXZe2X9moE",
            "width": "248",
            "height": "204"
          }
        ],
        "product": [
          {
            "image": "https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/BDkAAOSwA1pawWWP/s-l300.jpg",
            "name": "Details about NEW WRIGLEY'S AIRWAVES SUGAR FREE CHEWING GUM 3 PACK - 30 PIECES - 42g"
          }
        ],
        "review": [
          {
            "reviewdate": "2019-10-30",
            "reviewer": "peter55_1"
          },
          {
            "author": "peter55_1",
            "name": "Nice one",
            "reviewbody": "Hi there..Nice one..ok cool..many thanks..Peter",
            "datepublished": "30 Oct, 2019"
          },
          {
            "author": "spike.7900",
            "name": "Nice one !!!",
            "reviewbody": "Yes great !!!",
            "datepublished": "24 May, 2018"
          }
        ],
        "aggregaterating": [
          {
            "ratingvalue": "5.0",
            "reviewcount": "2"
          }
        ],
        "metatags": [
          {
            "og:image": "https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/BDkAAOSwA1pawWWP/s-l400.jpg",
            "twitter:card": "summary",
            "twitter:title": "NEW WRIGLEY'S AIRWAVES SUGAR FREE CHEWING GUM 3 PACK - 30 PIECES - 42g",
            "og:type": "ebay-objects:item",
            "og:site_name": "eBay",
            "msvalidate.01": "34E98E6F27109BE1A9DCF19658EEEE33",
            "og:title": "NEW WRIGLEY'S AIRWAVES SUGAR FREE CHEWING GUM 3 PACK - 30 PIECES - 42g 4009900360937 | eBay",
            "y_key": "0090e7e28a2554d4",
            "og:description": "Find many great new & used options and get the best deals for NEW WRIGLEY'S AIRWAVES SUGAR FREE CHEWING GUM 3 PACK - 30 PIECES - 42g at the best online prices at eBay! Free delivery for many products!",
            "twitter:image": "https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/BDkAAOSwA1pawWWP/s-l400.jpg",
            "layout": "main",
            "referrer": "unsafe-url",
            "fb:app_id": "102628213125203",
            "twitter:site": "@eBay",
            "twitter:description": "Find many great new & used options and get the best deals for NEW WRIGLEY'S AIRWAVES SUGAR FREE CHEWING GUM 3 PACK - 30 PIECES - 42g at the best online prices at eBay! Free delivery for many products!",
            "og:url": "https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/BDkAAOSwA1pawWWP/s-l400.jpg"
          }
        ],
        "cse_image": [
          {
            "src": "https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/BDkAAOSwA1pawWWP/s-l400.jpg"
          }
        ],
        "hproduct": [
          {
            "fn": "Details about NEW WRIGLEY'S AIRWAVES SUGAR FREE CHEWING GUM 3 PACK - 30 PIECES - 42g",
            "photo": "https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/BDkAAOSwA1pawWWP/s-l300.jpg",
            "currency": "GBP",
            "currency_iso4217": "826"
          }
        ],
        "listitem": [
          {
            "item": "Home, Furniture & DIY",
            "name": "Home, Furniture & DIY",
            "position": "1"
          },
          {
            "item": "Food & Drink",
            "name": "Food & Drink",
            "position": "2"
          },
          {
            "item": "Food Cupboard",
            "name": "Food Cupboard",
            "position": "3"
          },
          {
            "item": "Sweets & Chocolate",
            "name": "Sweets & Chocolate",
            "position": "4"
          },
          {
            "item": "Candies",
            "name": "Candies",
            "position": "5"
          },
          {
            "item": "Gummy, Soft Sweets & Marshmallows",
            "name": "Gummy, Soft Sweets & Marshmallows",
            "position": "6"
          },
          {
            "item": "See more Wrigley S Airwaves Menthol Eucalyptus Sugarfre...",
            "name": "See more Wrigley S Airwaves Menthol Eucalyptus Sugarfre...",
            "position": "1"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "customsearch#result",
      "title": "Airwaves Menthol & Eucalyptus 3x10er | Online kaufen im World of ...",
      "htmlTitle": "Airwaves Menthol &amp; Eucalyptus 3x10er | Online kaufen im World of ...",
      "link": "https://www.worldofsweets.de/Airwaves-Menthol-Eucalyptus-3x10er.311211.html",
      "displayLink": "www.worldofsweets.de",
      "snippet": "Multipack mit 3x10 zuckerfreien Kaugummi-Dragees mit Menthol- und \nEukalyptusgeschmack. Inhalt: 45g. Herkunftsland: USA. EAN: 4009900360937. \nArt.-Nr.: ...",
      "htmlSnippet": "Multipack mit 3x10 zuckerfreien Kaugummi-Dragees mit Menthol- und \u003cbr\u003e\nEukalyptusgeschmack. Inhalt: 45g. Herkunftsland: USA. EAN: \u003cb\u003e4009900360937\u003c/b\u003e. \u003cbr\u003e\nArt.-Nr.:&nbsp;...",
      "cacheId": "5xWyO_gVRoAJ",
      "formattedUrl": "https://www.worldofsweets.de/Airwaves-Menthol-Eucalyptus-3x10er.311211 .html",
      "htmlFormattedUrl": "https://www.worldofsweets.de/Airwaves-Menthol-Eucalyptus-3x10er.311211 .html",
      "pagemap": {
        "cse_thumbnail": [
          {
            "src": "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSBeGT1ypG_5KuTTlilOOrkqyjzIIVK_1ibx00UcNfp0-QML81xmqk-QfHF",
            "width": "225",
            "height": "225"
          }
        ],
        "metatags": [
          {
            "msapplication-tilecolor": "#D83434",
            "og:image": "https://www.worldofsweets.de/out/pictures/generated/product/1/540_340_75/airwaves-menthol--amp--eucalyptus-3er.jpg",
            "og:type": "product",
            "og:site_name": "https://www.worldofsweets.de/",
            "viewport": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2, minimum-scale=1",
            "og:title": "Airwaves Menthol & Eucalyptus 3x10er | Online kaufen im World of Sweets Shop",
            "og:url": "https://www.worldofsweets.de/Airwaves-Menthol-Eucalyptus-3x10er.311211.html",
            "msapplication-tileimage": "https://www.worldofsweets.de/out/worldofsweets/img/favicons/favicon_512x512.png",
            "og:description": "Airwaves Menthol & Eucalyptus 3x10er - Airwaves Menthol & Eukalyptus verbindet, was zusammen gehört. Die Kaugummi-Dragees kombinieren einen erfrischenden Eukalyptus-Geschmack mit dem intensiven Airwav"
          }
        ],
        "cse_image": [
          {
            "src": "https://www.worldofsweets.de/out/pictures/generated/product/1/540_340_75/airwaves-menthol--amp--eucalyptus-3er.jpg"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "customsearch#result",
      "title": "Swift JSON parsing array of dictionaries - Stack Overflow",
      "htmlTitle": "Swift JSON parsing array of dictionaries - Stack Overflow",
      "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60338583/swift-json-parsing-array-of-dictionaries",
      "displayLink": "stackoverflow.com",
      "snippet": "6 days ago ... Reason: products in the above JSON is not of type [[String: String]] . It is of type [[\nString: Any]] instead. That's the reason parsing is giving error.",
      "htmlSnippet": "6 days ago \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e Reason: products in the above JSON is not of type [[String: String]] . It is of type [[\u003cbr\u003e\nString: Any]] instead. That&#39;s the reason parsing is giving error.",
      "cacheId": "Ipcat4pAuKIJ",
      "formattedUrl": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/.../swift-json-parsing-array-of- dictionaries",
      "htmlFormattedUrl": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/.../swift-json-parsing-array-of- dictionaries",
      "pagemap": {
        "question": [
          {
            "image": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a",
            "upvotecount": "-2",
            "answercount": "2",
            "name": "Swift JSON parsing array of dictionaries",
            "text": "I am trying to parse this JSON file which returns an array of dictionaries. I mainly need to retrieve the 'barcode_number' and 'images' values of the dictionaries in order to use them in my...",
            "datecreated": "2020-02-21T12:22:11",
            "url": "share"
          }
        ],
        "answer": [
          {
            "upvotecount": "1",
            "text": "Reason: products in the above JSON is not of type [[String: String]]. It is of type [[String: Any]] instead. That's the reason parsing is giving error. Solution: You need to create a separate...",
            "datecreated": "2020-02-21T12:37:17",
            "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60338583/swift-json-parsing-array-of-dictionaries/60338812#60338812"
          },
          {
            "upvotecount": "0",
            "text": "try this: yes, it looks like a lot of work, but it wasn't. How did i do this? Easy: 1) enter your url in a webbrowser and copy the result 2) go to https://app.quicktype.io/ and enter the copy...",
            "datecreated": "2020-02-21T12:42:47",
            "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60338583/swift-json-parsing-array-of-dictionaries/60338906#60338906"
          }
        ],
        "person": [
          {
            "name": "Luca S"
          },
          {
            "name": "PGDev"
          },
          {
            "name": "Chris"
          }
        ],
        "metatags": [
          {
            "viewport": "width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "customsearch#result",
      "title": "Airwaves Menthol & Eucalyptus 3x10er Multipack",
      "htmlTitle": "Airwaves Menthol &amp; Eucalyptus 3x10er Multipack",
      "link": "https://fr.openfoodfacts.org/produit/4009900360937/airwaves-menthol-eucalyptus-3x10er-multipack",
      "displayLink": "fr.openfoodfacts.org",
      "snippet": "10 avr. 2018 ... Airwaves Menthol & Eucalyptus 3x10er Multipack. Code barre : 4009900360937 \n(EAN / EAN-13). La page de ce produit n'est pas complète.",
      "htmlSnippet": "10 avr. 2018 \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e Airwaves Menthol &amp; Eucalyptus 3x10er Multipack. Code barre : \u003cb\u003e4009900360937\u003c/b\u003e \u003cbr\u003e\n(EAN / EAN-13). La page de ce produit n&#39;est pas complète.",
      "cacheId": "n1RLGxrSrnQJ",
      "formattedUrl": "https://fr.openfoodfacts.org/.../4009900360937/airwaves-menthol-eucalyptus -3x10er-multipack",
      "htmlFormattedUrl": "https://fr.openfoodfacts.org/.../\u003cb\u003e4009900360937\u003c/b\u003e/airwaves-menthol-eucalyptus -3x10er-multipack",
      "pagemap": {
        "cse_thumbnail": [
          {
            "src": "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRIicojCdKeyBJkuzIZgC1qkkWHynDQQs-yjMOnGASpIczNComl2ya4aJQH",
            "width": "252",
            "height": "200"
          }
        ],
        "product": [
          {
            "gtin13": "4009900360937",
            "name": "Airwaves Menthol & Eucalyptus 3x10er Multipack",
            "brand": "Airwaves"
          }
        ],
        "imageobject": [
          {
            "license": "https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/",
            "thumbnail": "https://static.openfoodfacts.org/images/products/400/990/036/0937/ingredients_fr.4.200.jpg",
            "contenturl": "https://static.openfoodfacts.org/images/products/400/990/036/0937/ingredients_fr.4.full.jpg",
            "representativeofpage": "false",
            "imgid": "ingredients_fr",
            "caption": "Airwaves Menthol & Eucalyptus 3x10er Multipack - Ingrédients"
          },
          {
            "license": "https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/",
            "thumbnail": "https://static.openfoodfacts.org/images/products/400/990/036/0937/ingredients_fr.4.200.jpg",
            "contenturl": "https://static.openfoodfacts.org/images/products/400/990/036/0937/ingredients_fr.4.full.jpg",
            "representativeofpage": "false",
            "imgid": "ingredients_fr",
            "caption": "Airwaves Menthol & Eucalyptus 3x10er Multipack - Ingrédients"
          }
        ],
        "metatags": [
          {
            "msapplication-tilecolor": "#da532c",
            "og:image": "https://static.openfoodfacts.org/images/misc/openfoodfacts-logo-fr-356.png",
            "msapplication-config": "https://static.openfoodfacts.org/images/favicon/browserconfig.xml",
            "apple-itunes-app": "app-id=588797948",
            "twitter:card": "product",
            "twitter:title": "Airwaves Menthol & Eucalyptus 3x10er Multipack",
            "og:type": "food",
            "twitter:label1": "marque",
            "twitter:label2": "catégorie",
            "msapplication-tileimage": "https://static.openfoodfacts.org/images/favicon/mstile-144x144.png",
            "twitter:creator": "@OpenFoodFactsFr",
            "og:description": "Ingrédients, composition nutritionnelle et information sur les produits alimentaires du monde entier dans une base de données libre et ouverte",
            "twitter:data1": "Airwaves",
            "_globalsign-domain-verification": "2ku73dDL0bAPTj_s1aylm6vxvrBZFK59SfbH_RdUya",
            "fb:app_id": "219331381518041",
            "twitter:site": "@OpenFoodFactsFr",
            "viewport": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0",
            "twitter:description": "Ingrédients, allergènes, additifs, composition nutritionnelle, labels, origine des ingrédients et informations du produit Airwaves Menthol & Eucalyptus 3x10er Multipack",
            "flattr:id": "dw637l",
            "og:url": "https://fr.openfoodfacts.org/produit/4009900360937/airwaves-menthol-eucalyptus-3x10er-multipack"
          }
        ],
        "cse_image": [
          {
            "src": "https://static.openfoodfacts.org/images/misc/openfoodfacts-logo-fr-356.png"
          }
        ],
        "hproduct": [
          {
            "fn": "Airwaves Menthol & Eucalyptus 3x10er Multipack"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "customsearch#result",
      "title": "Airwaves Menthol & Eukalyptus (3 St.) Kaugummi | real",
      "htmlTitle": "Airwaves Menthol &amp; Eukalyptus (3 St.) Kaugummi | real",
      "link": "https://www.real.de/product/320670591/",
      "displayLink": "www.real.de",
      "snippet": "4009900360937. Herstellernummer. 133648005. Hersteller. Wrigley, Wrigley \nKaugummis, Wrigley Süßigkeiten & Gebäck. Gewicht. 50 g. Zutatenverzeichnis.",
      "htmlSnippet": "\u003cb\u003e4009900360937\u003c/b\u003e. Herstellernummer. 133648005. Hersteller. Wrigley, Wrigley \u003cbr\u003e\nKaugummis, Wrigley Süßigkeiten &amp; Gebäck. Gewicht. 50 g. Zutatenverzeichnis.",
      "cacheId": "EAaYPSRT6tAJ",
      "formattedUrl": "https://www.real.de/product/320670591/",
      "htmlFormattedUrl": "https://www.real.de/product/320670591/",
      "pagemap": {
        "offer": [
          {
            "pricecurrency": "EUR",
            "price": "2.56",
            "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
            "itemcondition": "http://schema.org/NewCondition"
          }
        ],
        "cse_thumbnail": [
          {
            "src": "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_yzLY6rSwIKrg5flkC2Zarb1TnLcEejdr-yRO_ShbUK4WQz7Sp78C3-o",
            "width": "225",
            "height": "224"
          }
        ],
        "product": [
          {
            "image": "https://media.real-onlineshop.de/images/items/1024x1024/dd6e657038ea57ce35ef738ae7c19a1e.jpg",
            "gtin13": "4009900360937",
            "name": "Airwaves Menthol & Eukalyptus (3 St.)",
            "description": "Produktbeschreibung Das original starke Geschmackserlebnis für den einzigartigen Airwaves Frische-Kick. Zuckerfreier Kaugummi mit Süßungsmitteln und Menthol- und Eukalyptusgeschmack. Zuckerfreih...",
            "sku": "320670591",
            "brand": "Wrigley"
          }
        ],
        "metatags": [
          {
            "og:image": "https://media.real-onlineshop.de/images/items/1024x1024/dd6e657038ea57ce35ef738ae7c19a1e.jpg",
            "theme-color": "#003A70",
            "og:type": "product",
            "og:site_name": "real.de",
            "og:title": "Airwaves Menthol & Eukalyptus (3 St.)",
            "product:price:amount": "2.56",
            "product:availability": "in stock",
            "og:description": "Das original starke Geschmackserlebnis für den einzigartigen Airwaves Frische-Kick. Zuckerfreier Kaugummi mit Süßungsmitteln und Menthol- und Eukalyptusgeschmack.",
            "fb:pages": "101656796570383",
            "fb:app_id": "198334153630763",
            "viewport": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1",
            "product:brand": "Wrigley",
            "product:price:currency": "EUR",
            "og:url": "https://www.real.de/product/320670591/"
          }
        ],
        "cse_image": [
          {
            "src": "https://media.real-onlineshop.de/images/items/1024x1024/dd6e657038ea57ce35ef738ae7c19a1e.jpg"
          }
        ],
        "hproduct": [
          {
            "fn": "Airwaves Menthol & Eukalyptus (3 St.)",
            "description": "Produktbeschreibung Das original starke Geschmackserlebnis für den einzigartigen Airwaves Frische-Kick. Zuckerfreier Kaugummi mit Süßungsmitteln und Menthol- und Eukalyptusgeschmack. Zuckerfreih...",
            "photo": "https://media.real-onlineshop.de/images/items/1024x1024/dd6e657038ea57ce35ef738ae7c19a1e.jpg",
            "currency": "EUR",
            "currency_iso4217": "978"
          }
        ],
        "listitem": [
          {
            "item": "https://www.real.de/",
            "name": "Startseite",
            "position": "1"
          },
          {
            "item": "Lebensmittel",
            "name": "Lebensmittel",
            "position": "2"
          },
          {
            "item": "Süßigkeiten & Gebäck",
            "name": "Süßigkeiten & Gebäck",
            "position": "3"
          },
          {
            "item": "Kaugummis",
            "name": "Kaugummis",
            "position": "4"
          },
          {
            "name": "Airwaves Menthol & Eukalyptus (3 St.)",
            "position": "5"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you only want to get metaTags?

Comment: Yes I need the fields of that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`Codable`** to parse the JSON `data`.

Below are the **models** to only parse the `metaTags` for `items`,

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let items: [Item]
}

struct Item: Codable {
    let pagemap: Pagemap
}

struct Pagemap: Codable {
    let metatags: [Metatag]
}

struct Metatag: Codable {
    let ogImage: String?
    let ogTitle: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case ogImage = "og:image"
        case ogTitle = "og:title"
    }
}
```

**Parse** the `data` like

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let response = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(response.items.map({ $0.pagemap.metatags.map({ $0.ogImage }) }))
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to print only the ogImage case, rather than print(response), how would I do it? Would it be print(response.items.first?.pagemap.metatags.first?.ogImage) ?

Comment: Use `response.items.map({ $0.pagemap.metatags.map({ $0.ogImage }) })`

Comment: You can also use `response.items.first?.pagemap.metatags.first?.ogImage` if only single item exist.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to PgDev's response.

In this step when you access the collection of images you will receive all images on a single index because the entire object is an array of dictionaries.

If you want to access images one by one and use them for different purposes you can do this by transforming the collection of images into an array that can be accessed by index.

```
let imageCollection = responseItems.items.map({$0.pagemap.metatags.map({$0.ogImage})})
```

This part is key:

```
let image = Array(imageCollection.joined())
print(image[0])
```